# Ruby: Implicit Block Converted to Proc

Tags: ruby, anonymous-function, proc

My understanding is that a block implicitly attached to a method must be yielded; it cannot be called. So I'm trying to understand why this works:

```
def execute_code
  proc.call
end

execute_code { "Why does this work?" } # => "Why does this work?"
```

Attaching a block to this code executes successfully.

Any insight? I haven't found any documentation hinting that an implicit block is automatically converted to a proc object and assigned to the variable `proc`.

Ruby 2.5.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Ruby 2.5.3, the [docs for `Kernel#proc()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html#method-i-proc) say:

> Equivalent to Proc.new.

and the [docs for `Proc.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Proc.html#method-c-new) say:

> Creates a new `Proc` object, bound to the current context. `Proc::new` may be called without a block only within a method with an attached block, in which case that block is converted to the `Proc` object.

which is what is happening in your example. You are calling `proc` in a method with a block, and the block is being converted to a `Proc.`

However this behaviour changes in later versions. If you try in Ruby 2.7,1 you will get a warning like this (although it will still work):

```
proc.rb:2: warning: Capturing the given block using Kernel#proc is deprecated; use `&block` instead
```

In Ruby 3, it won’t work at all (and in fact behaves as you seem to expect):

```
proc.rb:2:in `proc': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
    from proc.rb:2:in `execute_code'
    from proc.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

The [docs for 3.0.0](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Proc.html#method-c-new) are unchanged though. This looks like a bug in the docs (it has been [fixed in master](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/8da7f4abc779c6549833d718336d75aac98494b8)). It looks like this was first raised in the issue tracker in [2014](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10499) and then later in [2019](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15554).

Comment: Apparently, this was never even really intended. `Kernel#proc` was simply taking the topmost block off the stack, *assuming* it was the block passed to itself. The documentation that made it "official" came later. At least, that's the story I heard. Basically, a programming bug that was elevated to a feature which was later considered to be a mistake and thus removed but leaving it in the documentation, thus making the documentation buggy :-D